# Downloading source code for maven projects in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am working on a maven project in Eclipse. It has a dependency of Apache POI. In the POM.xml I have added the dependencies as -

```
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
...
```

Also, in Eclipse Preferences I have checked the `Download Artifact Sources` option. Still I am not able to see the POI source code. I get an error saying `Source not found`.

Do I need to explicitly add the source dependency jar in the POM.xml in this case or any other tweak is available?

[image]

Comment: Which version of poi do you have defined ?

Comment: poi.version=3.17

Comment: Have you checked the local cache `$HOME/.m2/repository/org/apache/poi/` ? Best is to remove the directory and restart clipse....

Comment: Does not work @khmarbaise

Comment: How are you trying to access the source code packages?

Comment: @khmarbaise By using the `Open Declaration` option in Eclipse

Comment: Does your project build fine on plain command line?